# How to get length of each string in a csv row then use that in formating number of elements to grab

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is what I have so far for some reason this will only grab one row. What I would like it to do is check all of the rows to get the length of each string then if the string length is <= 8 only grab first 8 elements or if the string length is >= 8 grab the first 10 elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 #example data from Book1.csv

 #hello 
 #thisislongerthaneight
 #whatareyoudoing
 #small



import csv 
import os 
import unicodecsv 

reader = csv.reader(open('Book1.csv', 'rb')) 
writer = csv.writer(open('Book2.csv', 'wb')) 
for row in reader: 
    length = len(row) 
    if length <= 8: 
        newRow = [elem[: 8] 
            for elem in row 
        ] 
    elif length >= 8: 
        newRow = [elem[: 10] 
            for elem in row 
        ] 
    writer.writerow(newRow)
```

So what I get out currenty is just this

```
 hello
```

What I would like to get out is this

```
hello
thisislong
whatareyou
small
```

Comment: Fix the indenting of your code. Your input data does not look like it's csv formatted.

Comment: I tried that same effect. @martineau

Comment: You are executing `.writerow()` once. How many lines do you expect will be written?

Comment: how ever many rows I have in Book1.csv @Goyo

Comment: One execution of `.writerows()` will write only one row. To write so many rows you have to call `writerows()` so many times.

Comment: @Goyo,  writerow seems to be in the loop so it would write as many times as it is called,  you also don't want to use writerows at all  unless you want `["foo"]` to be written as `f,o,o`.

Comment: Tried what? Your code is still isn't indented properly.

Comment: @Snowman41288, I think you are getting mixed up between lists and strings, each row is a list so checking the length of that has nothing to do with the length of the strings inside

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `writerow()` looks outside the loop to me. I guess it depends on how you interpret the broken indentation.

Comment: @Goyo, if it  were the last word is all your would see, the OP reckons they see hello which is the first so it has to be in the loop going on that basis. Their logic is completely wrong anyway, they are checking the row length when they want the string length.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Indeed. I didn't notice it was the first word, not the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the csv lib, you have a string per line so just open the file, check each string length not a row length, slice and write:

```
with open('Book1.csv') as f, open('Book2.csv'') as out:
      out.writelines(s[:8]+ "\n" if len(s) <= 8 else s[:10]+"\n"
                     for s in map(str.rstrip, f))
```

You need to strip the newlines as you have to add them back for the sliced strings, if you don't you could end up with two newlines at the end for the words that have less than eight characters.

If you had multiple words per line and wanted to apply the logic to each word:

```
writer.writerows([s[:8] if len(s) <= 8 else s[:10] for s in row] for row in reader)
```

Both would give you:

```
hello
thisislong
whatareyou
small
```

The only reason to use the latter would be if you had multiple comma separated words per line.

Comment: Thank you so much @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @Snowman41288, no prob, you're welcome.